# Is the viewDidLoad method naming misleading?

Tags: ios, api-design

When an instance of `UIViewController` is created, its view and all the `IBOutlet` are not loaded until it's required.
This means that, unlike all the other classes, having a fully initialized instance doesn't imply that all the properties are initialized and loaded.

This is unique behaviour, similar to async loading but without any delegate or callback method upon absolute completion of loading and initialized.

There are no other objects in Cocoa(Touch) that follow this same logic, even loading a `UIView` from a `nib` is synced.

Therefore is it fair to say the naming of the viewDidLoad method is misleading and/or incorrect convention within the context of Apple's other APIs?

Comment: "having a full initialized instance doesn't imply that all the properties are initialized." NO. Only the properties related to the UI are not initialised till they are required.

Comment: I'm not clear about what is the mistake you are trying to point out. The view related properties (outlets and view itself), won't be loaded until those are needed. When the viewDidLoad is being called the iOS loads the view and it's hierarchy to the memory.

When you just alloc a ViewController, the view related properties will be nil. When you present that, all view related properties will be initialised.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. Is there someway I can help to reopen it via editing to point out that you're contending the naming of this method is incorrect, rather than mistake? It seems that might be more literal, maybe. I don't really know. It's a brilliant question, and something I've been wondering about the last few days, as in "what sense of 'DidLoad' does this mean?" because it seems to be not fully created and loaded.

Comment: And @Rickster's answer is phenomenal. A massive provision of insight, understanding and wisdom.

Comment: I've had a crack at editing it. But I'm afraid some of the original intent might be lost.

Comment: @Confused I was not talking only about the name, but also in terms of api design. There are no other objects in Cocoa that can be created but are not fully ready just after the alloc/init. I can make another example if you set a value for an IBOutlet (that's by default implicit unwrapped) is very possible that the view is not loaded yet, therefore the application will crash. If the VC needs to be loaded in an async way at least the IBOutlet should be optionals.

Comment: I thought that might be the case - that my general and specific programming knowledge is nowhere near your shoelaces. And I have zero answers on how to re-open this question, or the reasons this is closed. It's clear (to my naive mind) that this is a much better question than most, and generally and specifically useful to understanding iOS. There's little opinion based about this, this deals in objective facts, as does @Rickster's answer.

Comment: I have to retract my sloppy, useless attempt at editing...

Comment: Voting to reopen. The *phrasing* of the question sounds opinion-based, but the *actual topic* of the question is confusion about how the Swift/Cocoa class initialization and delayed-loading systems work and what terms associated with them mean in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controller loading is a case of the pattern commonly known as *delayed initialization*. And this pattern isn't unique to view controllers: it occurs in several places in Cocoa, mostly related to nib/storyboard-based UI. For example, any custom class (such as a `UIView` subclass, or `NSView` subclass on macOS) that you put in a nib isn't fully "ready" for you until its `awakeFromNib` method is called.

When you load a nib or storyboard (or when the view controller system does so on your behalf), Cocoa (or Cocoa touch) initializes objects from their archived forms in the nib, then goes through each setting the values of any `IBOutlet` properties. Because that is a two-step process (and has to be, because archiving can't preserve links to other objects in the way that nibs need), there's an intermediate time where objects exist (that is, they've finished their `init` methods and `super.init` chains) but aren't fully set up to match the configuration you created in Interface Builder.

---

There seems to be some confusion here about just what "initialized" means. The requirement of the Swift language, and strong recommendation in ObjC, is that all properties / instance variable have *a defined value* by the time the initializer chain is finished running. To put it another way, if you get the value of a property or instance variable after initialization, *by reading your code you should know what that value will be*.

This definition stands in contrast to the behavior of non-ARC Objective-C: if you don't assign to instance variables during initialization, their values are *undefined*. They could be zero, they could be garbage, they could be discarded memory from something else.

ObjC with ARC partially enforces a solution to this issue in making sure that all variables are initialized to zero/nil even if you don't manually assign to them during initialization. And Swift enforces it further by requiring at compile time that you manually provide values in initialization (either by assigning to properties where they're declared, by assigning to them inside your `init` definition, or by declaring them as Optionals to make their default value nil).

---

So, when you're dealing with something that comes from a nib or storyboard, having a fully initialized instance means that all properties are "initialized" per the language definition — that is, their values are known. It doesn't necessarily mean that their values are "what you want them to be".

In particular, view controllers are intended to be used in delayed-initialization scenarios that last longer than just "during storyboard loading". For example, you can set up a whole interconnected network of view controllers (in a navigation stack, tab views, master/detail split views, etc). Initially, those VC instances are initialized and know some of their non-IBOutlet properties (such as their titles, for labeling inactive tabs in a tab bar). But the expensive UI infrastructure doesn't need to load until the system asks for the VC's view (typically when the user is about to see it).

Comment: I like your answer, let me add one comment.
Probably one bad feeling comes from the Apple decision to make the IBOutlet as implicit unwrapped. If we agree that a UIViewController can be initialized later in time, it should be clear from an API perspecitive that an IBOutlet can be there or not. So it should be a normal optional. Don't you agree?

Comment: In a sense, you're right — you could make your IBOutlets all true Optionals. But then you'd have lots of code for testing and unwrapping them. Implicitly unwrapped optionals (IUOs) are there as a compromise to make patterns like delayed initialization smoother. If you "know" that having a variable set to non-nil is a precondition for entering some chunk of code, but the compiler can't prove it (e.g. because the compiler doesn't know about nibs), you can make that variable an IUO so that your code isn't littered with optional-binding constructs that'll never be used.

Comment: This question and its answers, comments and closure perfectly demonstrate the good and bad of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get at the IBOutlets for your setup, I think the first call you can get the right values from is viewDidLayoutSubviews. That get's called a lot so use a bool to only call your setup stuff once.